# get pixel co-ordinates in image sector in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have an image and after I divide it into 10 sectors. I want to get the co-ordinates of all the black pixels in each sector.

```
% height and width are dimensions of black and white image
[hh,ww] = meshgrid( 1:height , 1:width );

% change to polar coordinates relative to the centroid 
[theta, r] = cart2pol(hh - centroid(1), ww - centroid(2));

% make divisions of image into Sectors each of 36 degree
E = 0:36:360;
[~, sectorid] = histc(theta * (180/pi), E); 

% count for each sector the number of black pixels
N = zeros(size(E));
N = arrayfun(@(k) nnz(bw(sectorid==k)==0), 1:max(sectorid));
```

N gives me the number of black pixels in each sector. I am not understanding how to find the co-ordinates of all pixels and then store them in a matrix.

Any help would be great!

Thank you.

Comment: hint: use `[x y]=find(...`

Comment: I know that we can use find() but how I can give specify that for number of black pixels in each sectors. The following gives the indices of all the black pixels.

    `[x1, y1] = find(bw==0); % bw is the image matrix`

Comment: do you understand the code you wrote ? what is `bw(sectorid==k)==0)` then?

Comment: For each sector we count the number of black pixels using nnz

Comment: @natan I have tried something like the below but that isn't working either,

Here's the sample image:-

[link](http://i.imgur.com/cgOL1yu.png)
    
I tried something like this to get the pixels but it ain't working : -

   `for i = 1 : max(SectorIdx)
       [cx1, cx2] = find(bw(SectorIdx == i) == 0)
   end`